# Where does the Linux kernel look for executables

Tags: path, kernel

First some background. I recently installed some software (TeX live actually), and the binaries were placed by the installer in a non-standard location (/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux). No problem, because I can change the $PATH in to include this directory. However, I use latex inside Makefiles, and Make said it could not find 'latex'. I eventually realized that Make asks the kernel to run latex in a shell-independent way. Thus I moved all my latex executables to /usr/local/bin and everything works, presumably because the kernel can now see the executables.

If this is correct, my question is: where does the kernel look for executables when asked to run a program when this is independent of a shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kernel doesn't look for executables - it is always told the (absolute or relative) path. All program executions (I believe) basically come down to calling the [execve()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) function, which needs to be told the path of the executable.

When you call programs using just their names, it's up to whatever is interpreting your commands (shell, make) to locate the program. Alternatively, library functions such as [execlp()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp) can be used, which do the path resolution themselves (see "Special semantics").